# Fechar janela tkinter após alguns segundos

Tags: python, tkinter

Opa galera, eu estou com uma duvida bem simples.

Preciso fechar a janela do tkinter após alguns segundos automaticamente, alguem pode me ajudar?

Segue o código:

```html
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import os

root = Tk()
root.iconbitmap('1.jpeg')

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
root.focus_set()  # <-- move focus to this widget
root.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: e.widget.quit())
my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("1.jpeg"))
my_label = Label(image=my_img)
my_label.pack()
root.mainloop()
exit()
```

Answer (score -1):

Adicione ao seu código essa linha: `root.after(ms,root.destroy)`

Exemplo:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import os

root = Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
root.focus_set()  # <-- move focus to this widget
root.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: e.widget.quit())
my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("1.jpeg"))
my_label = Label(image=my_img)
my_label.pack()
root.after(1000,root.destroy) # destroy after 1 second
```

O método `after` recebe um tempo em milissegundos e uma função que será executa após o tempo definido passar.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, deu certo!

Comment: @KoenomatachiSan Quase dois anos depois você vê a resposta? Tá bom né kkkk Antes tarde do que nunca xD